# Disable Button depending on the comparison between an attribute and list size in a Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-button

My code is the next one:

```
<aura:attribute name="listAddress" type="List" /> 
<aura:attribute name="rowValue" type="Integer"/>


<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" onclick="{!c.nextAddress}">&gt;</button>
```

I would like to disable the button when the **rowValue** attribute is bigger than the size of **listAddress**

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier solution would be to use [`lightning:button`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_button.htm) instead as it has a disabled property.

```
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label=">" onclick="{!c.nextAddress}" class="slds-grow"
    disabled="{!rowValue > listAddress.length}"/>
```

Note: check if listAddress.length or listAddress.size works. This is just a psuedo code.

---

If you really want to use a HTML button, you would have to use an `aura:if` or a boolean attribute in component:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!rowValue > listAddress.length}">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" onclick="{!c.nextAddress}"
        disabled="disabled">&gt;</button>

    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" 
            onclick="{!c.nextAddress}">&gt;</button>
    </aura:set>

</aura:if>
```

Comment: To use Lightning Button was the best idea. I have tried with listAddress.length, and worked well. 
The code I have used is the next one, and works properly: 
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label=">" onclick="{!c.nextAddress}" disabled="{! v.rowValue>v.listAddress.length}"/>

Thanks for the Help ;)

Comment: ah I missed the `v.` for accessing attribute. old visualforce coding habit :D

Answer (score 1):

Check for the size of listAddress in your js controller if it is greater than rowValue, then set another variable for eg. flag to true and use this variable in disabled property of the button.

JS Controller

```
if(rowValue > listAddress.length){
 component.set("v.flag",true);
}
else{
 component.set("v.flag",false);
}
```

Component

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" onclick="{!c.nextAddress}" disabled="{!v.flag}">&gt;</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think to use Lightning Button is much easier (Check the answer below)  but your idea  wasn't bad